# iPython, save the output of a code cell and still normally showing the ouput during execution

Tags: python, output, ipython, cell

So, the usual answer to this question is using the cell magic "%%caputre cap",
the problem is that it suppresses the normal output and to show it you have to run "cap.show()" after the execution of the cell.
When running a cell that takes a long time, like training a NN, this feature becomes a pain in the neck.
How can I run my code cell and have the real time output as usual and than be able to save it to a .txt file after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't IPython/Jupyter-specific, but here's a context manager I wrote for a similar purpose:

```py
import sys


class capture_stdout:
    """
    Context manager similar to `contextlib.redirect_stdout`, but
    different in that it:
      - temporarily writes stdout to other streams *in addition to*
        rather than *instead of* `sys.stdout`
      - accepts any number of streams and sends stdout to each
      - can optionally keep streams open after exiting context by
        passing `closing=False`

    Parameters
    ----------
    *streams : *`io.IOBase`
        stream(s) to receive data sent to `sys.stdout`

    closing : `bool`, optional
        if [default: `True`], close streams upon exiting the context
        block.
    """
    def __init__(self, *streams, closing=True):
        self.streams = streams
        self.closing = closing
        self.sys_stdout_write = sys.stdout.write

    def __enter__(self):
        sys.stdout.write = self._write
        if len(self.streams) == 1:
            return self.streams[0]
        return self.streams

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        sys.stdout.write = self.sys_stdout_write
        if self.closing:
            for s in self.streams:
                s.close()

    def _write(self, data):
        for s in self.streams:
            s.write(data)
        self.sys_stdout_write(data)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

You can pass however many streams you want, and it'll write to all of them *in addition to* regular `sys.stdout` in real time.  So for example if you wanted to show the live output, capture it for use later in your code, and also log it to a file, you could do:

```py
from io import StringIO


with capture_stdout(StringIO(), open('logfile.txt', 'w')) as (mem_stream, file_stream):
    print('some really long output')
    # etc...
    stdout = mem_stream.getvalue()
    

print(f"in str: {stdout}")
with open('logfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(f"in file: {f.read()}")
```

```
some really long output

in str: some really long output

in file: some really long output
```

It also shouldn't be too hard to turn into a cell magic that works the same way.  [Here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/custommagics.html)'s the `IPython` docs section on defining custom magics if you want to give it a shot.